# Convertir MySQL a LINQ (Entity Framework 5)

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

alguien sabe como puedo traducir la siguiente consulta MySQL a LINQ para poder utilizarlo con Entity Framework 5.0 (Desde ya agradezco cualquier ayuda que puedan brindarme)

```
select case when T.Count1 >= T.CountO then MaxValue1
            when T.Count1 = 0 and T.CountO > 0 then MinValue0
       end
       from ( select count(case when Status = 0 then 1 else NULL end)   as Count0,
                     count(case when Status = 1 then 1 else NULL end)   as Count1,
                     max(case when Status = 1 then Value else NULL end) as MaxValue1,
                     min(case when Status = 0 then Value else NULL end) as MinValue0
                     from TuTabla
       ) AS T
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: Solo he logrado consultas básicas, pero esto escapa de mis conocimientos en LINQ.

Comment: Entonces, intenta y agrega a tu pregunta tus intentos, en el sitio se da más atención a preguntas que demuestran intento de dar respuesta. Mira estas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822